# jQuery Need to reattach title to element onClick

Tags: jquery, onclick, title

Am using the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[title]').mouseover(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title'));
        // Using null here wouldn't work in IE, but empty string will work just fine.
        $this.attr('title', '');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
    });
    $('[data-title]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
        $this.removeAttr('data-title');
        $(this).click();
    });
});
```

The reason for this code is to eliminate the `title` attribute from `<a>` tags only when it is hovered on, because I happen to need the title attribute for this plugin called `mediaboxadvanced` because it uses the title attribute as the caption for image popups, which is what I want.  The reason I'm storing the title attribute inside of the data-title on hover, is because I don't want the HTML markup to show in the title and unable to find a solution for removing this HTML markup (which is ugly to see) that gets displayed via a tooltip (from the title attribute).  So, with that said, I don't think we need a tooltip at all, but I am having trouble reassigning the title attribute back from the `data-title` attribute onclick.

Actually, it would be sweet if we could somehow assign it back to the `<a>` tag just before the click event occurs, which is what I am trying to do in the code above.  But for some reason, the title attribute isn't being assigned here...

Comment: DO you have a data-title attribute in your markup? jquery data does not add an attribute. Also you are causing max-stack error by calling click inside the click event.

Comment: No, the data-title attribute is being populated via the `mouseover` code just above that.  Ahhh, so that explains why it isn't working... If you set a data attribute on an element, how can you call that same element if the `data-title` attribute is set on it and it is clicked?

Comment: It doesn't add any attribute. If you just say `.data()`. DO you need to add a data attribute why not bind click on anchor itself directly?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here... bind click on anchor?  Can you show me an example please?  Thanks a million  I'm not very familiar with binding events.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points

1. There is no `data-title` attribute associated with the `a` elements, you have only `title` attribute. So you need to change the selector
2. You are firing the on-click handler within the `click` handler with triggers a indefinite recursion causing the `Maximum recursion depth exceeded now` error

Update:
There is no need for all these things, the plugin gives us facility to extend it using a `linkmapper`.

At the bottom of the plugin file you have

```
Mediabox.scanPage = function() {
//  if (Browser.Platform.ios && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) return;  // this quits the process if the visitor is using a non-iPad iOS device (iPhone or iPod Touch)
//  $$('#mb_').each(function(hide) { hide.set('display', 'none'); });
    var links = $$("a").filter(function(el) {
        return el.rel && el.rel.test(/^lightbox/i);
    });
//  $$(links).mediabox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
    links.mediabox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
        var rel0 = this.rel.replace(/[\[\]|]/gi," ");
        var relsize = rel0.split(" ");
//      return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && el.rel.match(relsize[1]));

        var relsearch = "\\["+relsize[1]+"[ \\]]";
        var relregexp = new RegExp(relsearch);
        return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && el.rel.match(relregexp));
    });
};
```

Change it to

```
Mediabox.scanPage = function() {
//  if (Browser.Platform.ios && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) return;  // this quits the process if the visitor is using a non-iPad iOS device (iPhone or iPod Touch)
//  $$('#mb_').each(function(hide) { hide.set('display', 'none'); });
    var links = $$("a").filter(function(el) {
        return el.rel && el.rel.test(/^lightbox/i);
    });
//  $$(links).mediabox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
    links.mediabox({/* Put custom options here */}, function(el) {
    //This is the linkmapper function
        elrel = el.rel.split(/[\[\]]/);
        elrel = elrel[1];
        return [el.get('href'), $(el).data('title'), elrel];    // thanks to Dušan Medlín for figuring out the URL bug!
    }, function(el) {
        var rel0 = this.rel.replace(/[\[\]|]/gi," ");
        var relsize = rel0.split(" ");
//      return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && el.rel.match(relsize[1]));

        var relsearch = "\\["+relsize[1]+"[ \\]]";
        var relregexp = new RegExp(relsearch);
        return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && el.rel.match(relregexp));
    });
};
```

and then instead of using `title` to specify the title use `data-title` attribute in the markup

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JyaLedT5DLL9gbqVdmLx)

Comment: Nope, this just isn't working... arggg!  Not getting any errors, but just no luck at all with this!

Comment: why do you want the `title` back on if you click? is there another library which wants the title to be there?

Comment: Yes, `mediaboxadvanced` plugin needs the title in order to show captions under the images... http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced

Comment: It's a pretty huge plugin, so I'm not entirely familiar with how to change it's check within it from the `title` attribute to a `data-title` attribute.  Thought that this would be an easier approach, but now that I think about it, I don't think either approach is simple.

Comment: looks like you can extend it by passing a `linkmapper`, i haven't used it before

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selector from `$('[data-title]')` to `$('a[title]')`.

Comment: This doesn't work, and I get an error saying `Maximum recursion depth exceeded now`.

Comment: That's because you are calling the `click` event inside of your `click` callback.